# remotebuild fails to run cordova application on device or simulator

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I use Visual Studio 2015 with Cordova Tools. I run remotebuild at my mac and run the program at VS15. Remotebuild logs successful headers on screen but nothing runs.

```
GET /cordova/build/tasks/17748 200 2.065 ms - 692
```

My iphone 4 is already connected to Mac. 
I run it by `remotebuild --secure=false` and it says `remote build server listening on [http] port 3000`. It seems alright. 
What do I do wrong?

I have configured VS, tools -> options -> tools for apache cordova -> remote agent configuration, and set host ip with secure mode false. When I build, this is logged:

```
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\ÖmerAlper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CordovaApp\CordovaApp\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\ÖmerAlper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CordovaApp\CordovaApp\bin\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: iOS
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: ios
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: CordovaApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\ÖmerAlper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CordovaApp\CordovaApp
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\ÖmerAlper\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildServerUrl: http://192.168.1.21:3000/cordova
1>  ------    buildTarget: iOSEmulatoriPhone5S
1>  ------    language: en-US
```

and I keep getting this message. I stopped waiting at Attempt 100, because I thought nothing will happen anymore.

```
05:34:27 Checking on build status from http://192.168.1.21:3000/cordova/build/tasks/7288 [Attempt 1]
1>  uploaded - Uploaded build request payload.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem. I use wikitude plugin at my cordova app which is huge! It is about 113 mb. My project's total size becomes more than 250 mb with it. That is why "Uploaded build request payload" phase repeats more than 100 times. Without wikitude plugin, it works in a minute but now it is impossible to use wikitude.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using VS 2015 with Tools for Apache Cordova. Have you configured your VS for the [running](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757056.aspx) your application is remote device connected to a remote Mac machine?